# Принцип работы бесплатных хостингов

Tags: хостинг

Привет всем. Не могу понять одной вещи - какая выгода хостерам от их бесплатных услуг? Я помещаю сайты на hostinger.com. Мне выделяют абсолютно бесплатно 2 Гб под каждый сайт. Поддержка php,mysql( с условием не более 2000 запросов в 1 час) и т.д. и т.п. Какая им выгода от этого всего, если  они даже свои рекламы не размещают на моих сайтах?

Comment: а смысл почты гугл? ВК? фб? ж)

Comment: Ух ты, реклама на хешкоде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я с Хостингером не дружу, т.к. когда-то видел очень много отрицательных отзывов, поэтому опишу в целом. Вариантов масса, сейчас приведу первые, которые приходят мне в голову. Если звучит совсем наивно, то извините:)

1. Когда хостинг является просто довеском к остальным услугам компании(напр. Я.Народ, до недавнего времени)
2. Когда есть и бесплатные и платные тарифы. Т.е. если что-то не устраивает, то у нас можно докупить плюшки без лишних хлопот.
3. Когда платны услуги по доп. поддержке(напр. тикет в саппорт платный).
4. Раскрутка: сегодня бесплатно, а послезавтра придётся платить(может, совсем наивно:) ).
5. Просто добавляют рекламу(в т.ч. и в админке:) ).
6. Некуда девать мощности серверов.

Comment: @Алексей Лобанов.
Конечно, они предлагают платные услуги, но - я могу от них отказаться и сам все сделать! Рекламу они не ставят. "Сегодня - бесплатно, завтра - платно - тоже нет такого. Не пойму их выгоду.

Comment: >они предлагают платные услуги, но - я могу от них отказаться и сам все сделать! 

Вот поэтому я и пользуюсь буржуйским хостингом. Цены там просто копеечные по сравнению с нашими. Но - буржуи народ ленивый, лень им руками всё делать. А установка софта из админки - дело платное. Не всего, но... Бывает, что какой-нибудь магазин поставить из коробки со всем обслуживанием стоит больше, чем сам хостинг на 5 лет вперёд. И люди этим активно пользуются. Думаю, у нас тоже, потому что в большинстве случаев смотреть на это "я сам всё сделаю" без слёз просто нельзя.

Comment: @klopp, понятненько. Однако... я для тестирования заливаю сайты на хост. Редактирую, издеваюсь над их БД - удаляю, вставляю, перемещаю данные,делаю все что хочу, пользуюсь их статистикой, файловым менеджером и тд и тп - а им хоть бы что. Оно им надо? ))

Comment: @klopp , подскажите, что за "буржуйский" хостинг?) Поделитесь)

Comment: Да наберите в гугле "top 10 hosting", все хороши :) Только надо внимательно смотреть: где-то, например, может не быть crontab или чего-то ещё. Из них я имел дело с 5 или 6, но уже третий год для виртуального использую justhost.com

Comment: >Оно им надо?

А им пофиг. Все эти опции - издевательства над базой, установка скриптов и прочее - ничего не стоят вообще. Все затраты на них укладываются в одноразовое выделение "хостингово пространства".

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов, hostinger.com- этим я пользуюсь. Там все, что пожелаете,причем бесплатно.

Comment: @Deus, ни в коем случае не против хостингера, но только пхп/mysql это не "всё что надо", а minimum minimorum, для старта :) Кому-то хватает, а кому-то нет. Вот тут иначинается зароботок.

Comment: Честно говоря, мне не жалко 5р. в день на хостинг, поэтому я пользуюсь платными. А у платных хостингов, часто, есть адекватный саппорт и щадящие лимиты на ресурсы

Answer (score 0):

Не забывайте про рейтинг цитирования и раскрутку популярности. Тот же хостингер у всех на слуху, и шанс того, что кто-либо воспользуется их платными услугами возрастает.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов, вот - своим вопросом я уже поднял рейтинг западному хостингу, не так ли? ))

Comment: Рейтинг - нет, индекс цитирования - да. :)